# Python lxml gives entities for cyrillic characters

Tags: xml, lxml, python-3.8

I am trying to print a string containing cyrillic characters.

Code:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring('<root><child value="тест"/></root>')
child = root.find("child")
print(etree.tostring(child, encoding="unicode"))
```

...which will print:

```
<child value="&#x442;&#x435;&#x441;&#x442;"/>
```

This is what I was expecting:

```
<child value="тест"/>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put `method="html"` as parameter to `.tostring()`:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring('<root><child value="тест"/></root>')
child = root.find("child")
print(etree.tostring(child, method="html", encoding="unicode"))
```

Prints:

```
<child value="тест"></child>
```

Comment: Works, thanks. Will this always give me an intact string serialization, any side effects?

Comment: @usario Reading the [docs](https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.etree.html?highlight=tostring#lxml.etree.tostring) it should work. However, it all depends on input document.

Comment: @Andrey Kesely: The input document is a normal XML document with cyrillic texts.

Comment: @usario Then I see no problem.